# Problem on Swtich Case with nodeJS MongoDb Mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

:)

I'm learning to develop BACK END and I have a problem on a "Like /Dislike function".

This project work with : NodeJS / Express / Mongoose / MongoDB

The models looks like :

```
const bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userIdRegister: { type: String, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  mainperson: { type: String, required: true },
  imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
  pages: { type: Number, required: true },
  likes: { type: Number, required: false },
  dislikes: { type: Number, required: false },
  usersLiked: { type: String, required: false },
  usersDisliked: { type: String, required: false },
});
```

It works like this :

- when the user clicks on like (the server received the userId and like = 1 )
- when the user clicks on dislike (the server received the userId and like = -1)
- when the user clicks on second time on like / dislike  (the server received the userId and like = 0)

I would like to add 1 for like or dislike field and I would like to write in an array the userId of the liker (field : usersLiked and usersDisliked).
But when I received 0, I would like to decrease for 1 on like / dislike and remove the userId of the array

So I use Switch / Case

```
const Sauce = require("../models/Sauce_models");


exports.addAVote = (req, res, next) => {
  const like = req.body.like;
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  const bookId = req.params.id;
  
  Book
    .findOne({ bookId})
    .then(
      [{
        $switch:{
          branches: [
            { case: { $eq: [ like , 1 ] },
              then: { $inc: { likes: +1 }, $push: { usersLiked: userId } }},

            { case: { $eq: ["$like" , -1] },
              then: { $inc: { dislikes: +1 }, $push: { usersDisliked: userId } }},

            { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$like" , 0 ] },
                              { $in: [ userId , "usersLiked" ] }]},
              then: { $inc: { likes: -1 },
                      $pull: { usersLiked: userId }}},

            { case: { $and: [ {$eq: [ "$like" , 0 ]},
                              { $in: [ userId , "usersDisliked" ] }]},
              then: { $inc: { dislikes: -1 },
                      $pull: { usersDisliked: userId }}},
          ],
        }
      }]
    )
    .then(() =>
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Vote enregistrée,   :( ",
    })
  )
    .catch(
      (error) =>
        res.status(400).json({ error }) && console.log("big problem")
    );
```

I read a lot of doc (docs.mongodb.com, mongoosejs.com/docs,  some questions on stackoverflow, etc ...) but I don't understand why it doesn't work.
If you have some questions, ask me and if my explains are clear, can anybody help me ? please .
Thank you

Comment: Try with an aggregation query (instead of find) - it has a `$switch` operator you can use.

Comment: Ok thank  I gonna have a look